# Python class adding fractions

Tags: python, class, fractions

I have this class which takes a whole number and a fraction, and adds them together. The problem, however, is that the `__add__` function here converts the answer to a `__str__` so when I try and print the `__repr__` on the answer to an added question it just prints a `str` of the answer.

```
from fractions import Fraction

class MixedNumber(object):
   def __init__(self, whole_number, fraction):
        self.whole_number = whole_number
        self.fraction = fraction

   def __repr__(self):
       return "MixedNumber({}, Fraction({}, {})".format(self.whole_number, self.fraction.numerator, self.fraction.denominator)

   def __add__(self, g):
       summed = 0
       for v in (self.whole_number, g.whole_number, self.fraction, g.fraction):
           summed = Fraction(summed.numerator * v.denominator +
                          v.numerator * summed.denominator,
                          summed.denominator * v.denominator)
       whole = summed.numerator // summed.denominator
       remainder = Fraction(summed.numerator * whole.denominator -
                     whole.numerator * summed.denominator,
                     summed.denominator * whole.denominator)
       return '{} and {}'.format(whole,remainder)

if __name__=='__main__':
    x = MixedNumber(3, Fraction(1, 3))
    y = MixedNumber(-1, Fraction(2, 5))
    z = x + y
    print(z)
print(z.__repr__())
```

For example:
The output to this is

```
2 and 11/15
'2 and 11/15'
```

When it should be

```
2 and 11/15
MixedNumber(2, Fraction(11, 15))
```

Any help fixing this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return a new instance of `MixedNumber` instead:

```
return MixedNumber(whole, remainder)
```

or, to make it more sub-class-friendly, of `type(self)`:

```
return type(self)(whole, remainder)
```

Now your code prints:

```
>>> x = MixedNumber(3, Fraction(1, 3))
>>> y = MixedNumber(-1, Fraction(2, 5))
>>> z = x + y
>>> print z
MixedNumber(2, Fraction(11, 15)
>>> print repr(z)
MixedNumber(2, Fraction(11, 15)
```

but you could print the old result of `__add__` explicitly:

```
>>> print '{} and {}'.format(z.whole_number, z.fraction)
2 and 11/15
```

You could make that your `__str__` method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} and {}'.format(z.whole_number, z.fraction)
```

after which your `print` statements would be:

```
>>> print z
2 and 11/15
>>> print repr(z)
MixedNumber(2, Fraction(11, 15)
```

Comment: The OP could also add a `__str__` method that returns `'{} and {}'.format(self.whole_number, self.fraction)`, so that `print z` would show `2 and 11/15` and `print repr(z)` would show `MixedNumber(2, Fraction(11, 15))`.

Comment: It looks like a closing parenthesis is missing from the "print" outputs in your example.  It doesn't change anything, but just an observation.

Comment: @SethMMorton: The *original* `__repr__` is missing the closing parenthesis, yes.